# "Global" core data in Document-Based App

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsdocument

Ok so I have a document-based app, which is running pretty well so far. It essentially represents a course/camp that students would attend. So each document represents a separate course… everything is fine there, I use core data to add and remove students/teachers and a bunch of other stuff.

But here is my question, I want the user to be able to add Schools to the application and have access to them in any document they might create, note the student and the school have a relationship between one another.

I have done some reading on "Global Persistent Stores" but I'm not quite sure if thats what I need. Can anyone point me down the right road.

Sorry for the long question and thanks for any help you give.

Answer (score 0):

The core question is, should there only be one file and each "document" is part of that core file or should there be multiple files with multiple documents?

If there is only one file then you would use a single Core Data store across the entire application and then each "document" would be an entity or sub-heirarchy of the main model.

If it is a document of documents then things get a little more interesting.